# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm really struggling to work out where my issue lies here, I have changed a lot of code recently and now I am met with this issue

```
   ERROR  Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Navigation. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. undefined                  useRef
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    in Navigation (at App.tsx:96)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at createAnimatableComponent.js:599)
    in withAnimatable(View) (at App.tsx:89)
    in App (at mobile/index.js:28)
    in HeadlessCheck (at renderApplication.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
```

Presumably this is referring to my Navigation class, which I will share below, I am not particularly educated on the concept behind hooks and this issue is throwing me

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, NavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useStore } from '_src/store';
import { logScreenView } from '_utils/analytics';

import { SharedStackParamList } from './shared/SharedStack';
import { getSharedScreens } from './shared/Shared.screens';

import ErrorBoundary from '../components/atoms/ErrorBoundary';
import { modalOptions } from './StackOptions';
import { BLACK } from '_styles/colors';

const SharedStack = createStackNavigator<SharedStackParamList>();

export const Navigation = () => {
  const rootStore = useStore();
  const { authStore } = rootStore;
  if (authStore.token === undefined) return null;

  const routeNameRef = React.useRef<string>();
  const navigationRef = React.useRef<NavigationContainerRef>();

  function onReady() {
    routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;
  }

  function onStateChange() {
    const previousRouteName = routeNameRef?.current;
    const currentRouteName = navigationRef?.current?.getCurrentRoute()?.name;

    if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
      logScreenView({ screen_name: currentRouteName, screen_class: currentRouteName });
      routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
    }
  }

  // Return main stack
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: BLACK, opacity: 1 }}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef as any} onReady={onReady} onStateChange={onStateChange}>
          <SharedStack.Navigator screenOptions={modalOptions} mode="modal">
            {getSharedScreens().map(({ name, options, component }, i) => {
              // @ts-ignore
              return <SharedStack.Screen key={i} name={name} options={options} component={component} />;
            })}
          </SharedStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

If anyone can help me understand hooks a bit better and help me out with this issue, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [rules of hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#breaking-rules-of-hooks)
([page in the old React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html))

Hooks always need to be called in the same order (so adding new hooks conditionally is not allowed). Your code is breaking this rule, because you are using the `useRef` hooks after conditionally returning null.

The fix is very simple: Move the `useRef` usages above the `if (authStore.token === undefined) return null;` and you're good.

Comment: Unbelievable... thank you for that, and for linking that page, I will brush myself up so I can avoid silly things like this in future!

Comment: I was getting the same hooks error because I rendered 1 of 2 buttons, conditionally, in my navigation bar ("Login" or "Logout"). If when logged in I moved to another screen, returned, and then logged out, the error would trigger. I found that I had to call the hook I called in the LoginButton component in my LogoutButton component, even though I wasn't using it—but, that indeed solved the error I was getting. Thank you!